# How to store user input of round numbers in an Array

Tags: arrays, c, input, comparison

I have a problem to solve which is. I have to make a program which will take 2 numbers from the sequence of numbers and compare them if it's '<' '>' or '=' and the list of numbers needs to end with number 0. So basically I have a sequence of numbers {5, 7, 8, 4, 3, 3, 0} and the program have to check by couples 5,7 (it is 5 < 7) then it will go to 8, 4 (it is 8 > 4) then 3, 3 so it is 3 = 3. And the 0 is basically as the exit.

So far I wrote down the comparison of the numbers but now I only have a program which takes 2 inputs from the user and compares them. But I kinda need to specify for the user let's say to enter 11 numbers which will end with 0 (as 0 will not be counted to the comparison) and store those numbers in an array and then let the program to compare the 2 numbers after each other (in a sequence) with <, > or =.

Thanks in advance guys. I'm kinda new to C and these arrays and specially malloc, calloc, realloc are really complicated for me.

So far my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define post 10
int main(){

    int a, b;


    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

    if (a > b)
    {
        printf("%d > %d\n", a, b);
    }
    else if(a < b)
    {
        printf("%d < %d\n", a, b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d = %d\n", a, b);
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create large array and then input how many number you want to compare. Then you can use `for` to walk through the numbers in the array and compare them.

Here is exemple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
    int arr[SIZE] = {0};

    printf("Enter number: ");
    
    int number;
    int counter = 0;   
    
    while (1)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1)
        {
            printf("Invalid number!");
            return 1;
        }
        arr[counter] = number;
        if(number == 0) {break;}
        counter++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i+=2)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        {
            printf("%d > %d\n", arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        }
        else if(arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
        {
            printf("%d < %d\n", arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d = %d\n", arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        }      
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter number: 1 2 3 4 5 5 0
1 < 2
3 < 4
5 = 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information helped a lot. Just the thing is I need to have uneven set of numbers in my array cause they want me to end the sequence of numbers with 0 which is basically gonna be like the exit number. So for example if I have an array of numbers {1,2,3,4,0} it would compare 1<2, 3<4, 0 = end.

Comment: @Neolix I changed the code under your conditions, will this answer suit you?

Comment: Oh wow, I just tested it out and it work just as I expected it stays in the look until I enter 0 at the end! Thanks a lot I really like this answer :) Much appreciated!!!

Comment: @Neolix No problems :). You also can mark the answer as "accepted" if it works as you expexted)